# Carregar DataGridView com MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

Tenho o seguinte problema para exibir os dados em um gridView puxando do banco MySQL

```
public string CarregarAluno()
    {
        string retorno = "";

            string sql = "select * from alunos";

            MySqlConnection conn = CriarConexao();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(data);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            retorno = "";

        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        { retorno = "Erro ao Carregar Grid: " + ex.Message; }

        finally { if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close(); }

        return data;
    }
```

O "return data;" fica sublinhado com a seguinte mensagem: "Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo System.Data.Data.Table em String "

Comment: data é um `DataTable` como que você quer retornar em um método que espera uma `string` ? https://www.treinaweb.com.br/curso/csharp-basico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A assinatura do método `CarregarAluno` está retornando uma `string` e em determinado momento você tenta retornar um `DataTable`. Esse é o seu principal problema de compilação.

Para resolver, altere a assinatura do seu método para `public DataTable CarregarAluno()`.

E o corpo do método para

```
string sql = "select * from alunos";

MySqlConnection conn = CriarConexao();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

DataTable data = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(data);

try
{
   conn.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   conn.Close();
   return data;
}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{ 
   throw new Exception($"Erro ao Carregar Grid: {ex.Message}"); 
}
finally 
{
   if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close(); 
}
return null;
```

Comment: Se continuar algum erro de compilação, adicione aqui nos cometários que tento arrumar o código.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

João Víctor,

o problema está no tipo do método

> public DataTable CarregarAluno()

Altere para

```
public DataTable CarregarAluno()
{
    string retorno = "";

    string sql = "select * from alunos";

    MySqlConnection conn = CriarConexao();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(data);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        retorno = "";
        return data;
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    { 
        retorno = "Erro ao Carregar Grid: " + ex.Message; 
    }

    finally 
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Agora esta com erro assim: https://i.imgur.com/EcaRsbj.png

Answer (score 1):

Não precisa da classe [MySqlDataAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx) (*que é desnecessário, inclusive tem um desempenho baixo pela sua estrutura*), só assim já resolveria, ***exemplo***:

```
public DataTable CarregarAluno()
{
    string sql = "select * from alunos";
    MySqlConnection conn = CriarConexao();
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    data.load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    conn.Close();
    conn.Dispose();
    return data;
}
```

o seu retorno também estava errado, o método deve retornar o [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx).